# How to determine splitting field on $\mathbb{Q}$ of $f(X)= x^{15}-x^8-x^7+1$ and determine the degree over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $$f(X) \in \mathbb{Q} $$ such that $$f(X)= X^{15}-X^8-X^7+1=0$$
       Determine splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $f(X)$

I know that i have to find roots of f but I have trouble.

$$\small f(X)=(x^{8}-1)(x^7-1)
=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)(x^7-1)
=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-1)
=(x-1)^2(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

So root are $\pm i, \pm 1, \pm \sqrt[4]{-1}$ and  $\sqrt[7]{-1} $

So now 
the splitting field over $\mathbb {Q}$ is  $\mathbb {Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{-1},\sqrt[7]{-1})$ ?

Comment: HINT: $f(x) = (x^8 - 1)(x^7 - 1)$.

Comment: Ok thank you ,but how I can find that, intuition? @connorharris

Comment: The fact that $x^{15} = x^7 x^8$ should have been a clue to the possible factorings.

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Comment: @AlessandroRecchia: Technics! (Type $\texttt{factor(x^15-x^8-x^7+1)}$ [here](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html).) Joking of course.

Comment: I have to do that by hands eheh @metamorphy

Answer (score 1):

Hint.- A useful factorization of your polynomial is $$f(x)=(x^8-1)(x^7-1)$$
$$x^8-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)$$ $$x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$$
so the corresponding roots are
$$\pm1,\pm i,\frac{\sqrt2(1\pm\sqrt i)}{2},\frac{\sqrt2(-1\pm\sqrt i)}{2}$$ and
 $$1,\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}; k=1,2,3,4,5,6$$

from which your splitting field $K|\mathbb Q$ simplifying carefully, when elements are not $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent (for example i and -i and remember that $x^7-1$ defines an easy cyclotomic field of degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: Thank you so so much !!

Comment: You are welcome. For the degree, take the cyclotomic field above mentioned and use multiplication of degrees.